# Can I read object values in Javascript/Typescript without evaluating them?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this module

```js
export default () => ({
  environment: process.env.ENVIRONMENT,
  port: process.env.PORT
  database: {
    host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
    port: process.env.DATABASE_PORT,
    username: 'postgres',
    password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME,
  },
  awsSqsDefaultQueueUrl: process.env.AWS_SQS_DEFAULT_QUEUE_URL,
  sqsEndpoint: process.env.SQS_ENDPOINT,
})
```

I want to read it and create a flat key/value object that flattens its keys only if the value starts with `process.env`, like so:

```js
{
  ENVIRONMENT: configuration().environment,
  PORT: configuration().port,
  DATABASE_HOST: configuration().database.host
  DATABASE_PORT: configuration().database.port
  ...
}
```

`database.username` wouldn't be in the new object key because its value doesn't start with `process.env`.

The only way I can think where I can read the key value without before its evaluated is by loading the file as string and then parse it using regex. But that feels wrong.

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an idea:

```js
const settings = () => ({
    environment: process.env.ENVIRONMENT,
    port: process.env.PORT,
    database: {
        host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
        port: process.env.DATABASE_PORT,
        username: 'postgres',
        password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
        database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME,
    },
    awsSqsDefaultQueueUrl: process.env.AWS_SQS_DEFAULT_QUEUE_URL,
    sqsEndpoint: process.env.SQS_ENDPOINT,
});

function parseEnvSettings() {
    // test values
    process.env.ENVIRONMENT = "TEST";

    const str = settings.toString();
    const pattern = /process\.env\.[a-zA-Z0-9_]+/g;

    // get your property names
    const matches = [...str.match(pattern).values()];

    // build your flat settings object
    const parsedSettings = {};
    matches.forEach(property => {
        parsedSettings[property.substr(property.lastIndexOf(".") + 1)] = eval(property);
    });

    // here you go
    console.log(parsedSettings);
}

parseEnvSettings();
```

Produces:

```js
{
  ENVIRONMENT: 'TEST',
  PORT: undefined,
  DATABASE_HOST: undefined,
  DATABASE_PORT: undefined,
  DATABASE_PASSWORD: undefined,
  DATABASE_NAME: undefined,
  AWS_SQS_DEFAULT_QUEUE_URL: undefined,
  SQS_ENDPOINT: undefined
}
```

Comment: THANKS @Arash this is a great solution I was not aware `settings.toString()` would return the function as is without evaluating it. It worked like a charm. Just not sure about the eval() but I guess there's no alternative.

Comment: Yes, definitely beef up validation and security around it. Also, I didn't point out that you could simply iterate over the `process.env` object itself and pick up variables using something like `Object.entries(process.env).map(([key, value]) => { ...})` as I figured you would have already thought about that, and perhaps there was a reason you were only interested in env variables that were references in that particular function.